# get a part of a line after grep

Tags: unix, file, grep

I have a huge file on my unix server from which I need to extract certain parts

The format of the line is

```
aNumber timestamp commandInformation
```

I use the command

```
grep LATENCY file.log | grep CMDTYPE=NEW
```

to filter out certain lines that I want. I only want the part timestamp and the last 9 characters from the line to be returned, not the complete line. How can I do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `awk(1)`:

```
awk ' { print $2" "substr($0,length($0)-8) }'
```

Answer (score 13):

`cut` must do the job

```
grep something somewhere | grep againsomething | cut -f2 -d' '
```

Comment: Edit queue is full, but here's a helpful link for `cut` usage: https://www.computerhope.com/unix/ucut.htm

Answer (score 6):

You can do it all with `grep` using `-o` which outputs only the match and not the whole line.

Assuming you can create a regex for the timestamp and the rest of the line, you could simply add:

```
... | grep -o regex
```

*[Added answer for anyone else who lands here trying to extract part of a line using `grep` where the regex is the part they want to extract.]*

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to argue perl is a better choice than awk here:

```
perl -ne 'next if ! (/LATENCY|CMDTYPE=NEW/ && /^\d+.*\s+(.*)\s+.*(.{9})$/); print "$2 $3\n";'
```

The regex is more robust, allowing you to omit lines that don't match the stricter pattern.  The awk scripts above are going to see overflows in the substr call (I honestly dont' know what negative indices do in awk) if you feed it broken input like partial lines from the end of a log.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk` as follows:

```
grep LATENCY file.log | grep CMDTYPE=NEW | awk '{print $2,substr($0,length($0)-9,9)}'
```

Comment: Wouldn't using $0 ensure you display the end of the line instead of just the end of the 3rd word?

Comment: @Yannick: yes, I assumed for no reason that 'commandInformation' would be just one word. Fixed the post with your suggestion, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No need to use grep, awk can do that as well:

```
awk '/LATENCY/ && /CMDTYPE=NEW/ {print $2 " " substr($0, length($0)-8)}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do everything with sed alone:

```
$ echo "234432 12:44:22.432095 LATENCY blah CMDTYPE=NEW foo bar 123456789" | \
sed -n '/LATENCY/!b;/CMDTYPE=NEW/!b;s/^.\+\s\+\([0-9:.]\+\)\s.\+\(.........\)$/\1 \2/; p'
12:44:22.432095 123456789
```